# CTE Functionality followed by Delete statement fails with Syntax error

Tags: common-table-expression, hana

SAP HANA SQL with two Common CTE's and followed by delete SQL on a regular Table. The SQL execution fails with incorrect syntax. Below is the error code and the HANA SQl script. When replaced the 'DELETE FROM' to 'SELECT * Start', the SQL execution works as expected.

Could one of you please let us know the proper syntax to delete the records?

```sql
WITH CTE_A AS
(
  SELECT COL_1 FROM TABLE_A WHERE
  CONDITION1 = 'ABC'
  AND CONTITION2 = 'XYZ'
),

CTE_B AS
(
  SELECT COL_1, COL_2 FROM TABLE_A WHERE
  CONDITION3 = 'DEF'
  AND COL_1 IN (SELECT COL_1 FROM CTE_A)
)

DELETE FROM TABLE_A
WHERE ACCOUNT_NO IN (SELECT COL_2 FROM CTE_B);
```

Error:

> (dberror) [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "DELETE": line 64 col 0 (at pos 2273);

Answer (score 0):

CTE's in SAP HANA only supports SELECT statements.
UPDATE/ DELETE statements and recursive CTE's are not supported.

You can use subqueries to achieve the same functionality as shown below.

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_A
WHERE ACCOUNT_NO IN (SELECT COL_2 FROM 
                        ( SELECT COL_1, COL_2 FROM TABLE_A WHERE
                          CONDITION3 = 'DEF'
                           AND COL_1 IN ( SELECT COL_1 FROM TABLE_A WHERE
                                          CONDITION1 = 'ABC'
                                          AND CONTITION2 = 'XYZ'
                                         )
                        )
                     ) ;
```

Comment: Similar topic has been discussed before in stack link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487648/how-to-use-with-clause-insert-query-in-sap-hana

Comment: I think another option is to create temporary views as discussed in above link. The solution depends on if you need to use the temporary results anywhere else, other than the delete query.